# Java: Get instance of super class from subclass

Tags: java

Consider I have a class like below.

```
public class SuperClass
{
  private String a;
  private String b;
  //getter/setters
}
```

And a subclass

```
public class ChildClass extends SuperClass
    {
      private String c;
      private String d;
      //getter/setters
    }
```

In another class I have an object of the ChildClass. This object has both the parent and child class member variables populated with data. 
Using this object, I need to get an instance of parent class, i.e, an object which only has the variables in the parent class (i.e., a and b). How can I achieve it ?

Comment: Most of the time it is sufficient for treating object of ChildClass as SuperClass. What is the background that you should not include `c` and `d` in the object ?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Every instance of `ChildClass` *is* an instance of `SuperClass`. Why do you need to create an instance of `SuperClass` that *isn't* an instance of `ChildClass`?

Comment: I'm converting this object to json and it shouldn't be having the child class fields. Can't use @JsonIgnore because the child class fields are needed in json for some other scenario.

Comment: Have you looked at @JsonFilter with SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(ignorableFieldNames) for run-time decisions of what to serialize ?  eg https://proliferay.com/create-json-by-jackson-api/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a step back and understand what happens when you create an instance of the `ChildClass`. A memory location is made to store the fields of `ChildClass` and `SuperClass`. Now you cannot make that memory location "forget" the `ChildClass` fields and retain only the `SuperClass` fields. The best you can do is make the `ChildClass` fields `null`.

So to do what you want, you'll have a create a **new** object. You can do so by using a method like this:

```
public class ChildClass extends SuperClass {
    private String c;
    private String d;

    public SuperClass getSuperClassInstance() {
        SuperClass sc = new SuperClass();
        sc.a = this.a; //or use getters/setters
        sc.b = this.b; //you might need to deep clone objects
        return sc;
    }
}
```

As @ruakh said, merely casting to `SuperClass` is not enough as the data can be retrieved by casting it back to `ChildClass` as long as it is pointing to the same memory location.

**Update** based on comments

So this **is** an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)!

You can annotate the fields in your child class by `@JsonIgnore` or do it at class level using `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "c", "d" })`.

Also, the answer in [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912647/only-serialize-superclass-fields-to-json-with-jackson) should help.

If you need to serialize those fields in some other case, you can use [JSON Views](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation).

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by casting the class, if you have an `ChildClass` instance, you can get the `SuperClass` with the following command:

```
SuperClass sc = (SuperClass) childClass;
```

or

```
SuperClass sc = childClass;
```

As the comments bellow say, you don't really need the cast in this case, just making a `SuperClass` variable receiving your `ChildClass` is enough.

This happens because the **Upcast** (from child to super) is always possible, so it's safe to do it implicit. Only needing to explicit in cases of **Downcast**.

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-casting) you can learn more about java casting.

Comment: As you probably realize, this doesn't actually create a new instance; `sc` and `childClass` will refer to the same object, with the same fields, and `((ChildClass)sc)` will still work the same as `childClass`.

Comment: You don't need to cast - you can just say `SuperClass sc = childClass;`. Casting doesn't change anything about the instance.

Comment: As @ruakh pointed out 'sc' has the fields of child class as well. I need an object which has the parent class fields alone. I'm converting this object to json and it shouldn't be having the child class fields.